# Angular 4 nested object can not read null value error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a json object coming from angular service.data is like this

```
data={
   id: 334,
   name:'Tom Miller',
   address: {
          street: '133 Jackson St.',
          state: 'CA'
          }
     }
```

In my template I have following from my table

```
 <tr>
     <td> {{data.name}}</td>
     <td> {{data.address.state}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Program will not display zip value instead it gives error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null
```

In my interface address is optional field set as  address?:...

Please let me know how to fix this error Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use an `ngIf`?

Comment: address is miss-spelled in your template...

Comment: corrected the spelling mistake. Actually real computer is work cant log from there so I have to re type every thing.

Comment: ngif where? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Angular `?.` safe navigation operator exists exactly to address this problem. It should be used on every property that may not be present:

```
   <tr>
     <td> {{data.name}}</td>
     <td> {{data.address?.state}}</td>
   </tr>
```

Since the problem results from the fact that `address` is optional in JSON, this is how it should be handled in this case.

Another option is to use `ngIf` directive on elements that contains references to a missing object, but it is usually applicable when `data` is unavailable in whole (e.g. when HTTP request is in progress).

Answer (score 0):

### Option #1 - Display `null` value as ""

By default if a variable or json value resolves to null, Angular will take that as an empty string, so it shouldn't cause an error.

So your code should actually work fine (once typo is corrected), providing that that json key does actually exist. *(But do check your spelling of **`address`**  as there seems to be some inconsistency in your code)*

---

### Option #2 - Check value exists before displaying

**You can check whether or not a value is present and not `null`, using [`ngIf`](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html).**

As the documentation says, an element which resolves to false, will be removed from the DOM:

> Removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an
>   {expression}. If the expression assigned to ngIf evaluates to a falsy
>   value then the element is removed from the DOM, otherwise a clone of
>   the element is reinserted into the DOM.

So in your case, your template code would look like:

```
<tr>
    <td> {{data.name}}</td>
    <td> 
        <span *ngIf="data.address.state">{{data.address.state}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*Note that you need to apply the ngIf to a span (or other element) within the table cell, to avoid breaking tour HTML table.*

Comment: `*ngIf="data.address.state"` will fail for the same reason. You likely meant `*ngIf="data.address"`.